# C++/CLI targetting .NET Framework 2.0 gives invalid metadata operation error

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, console, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build an application which I require it to be targetting .NET Framework v2.0. As you've probably told from the title, the language I am using is C++ .NET. For some reason, when I include Windows.h in stdafx.h, I get the following errors:

> 1>MSVCMRT.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0001e2).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0001e6).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000c0).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000c2).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000a6).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000a9).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(ManagedMain.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000bf).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(ManagedMain.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000c1).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000e9).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000ec).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(pureMSILcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c000199).
>   1>MSVCMRT.lib(pureMSILcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c00019a).
>   1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors

If I remove #include < Windows.h > the application compiles perfectly fine. It appears to be a problem with including the Windows.h header file for some reason. I am compiling using the /clr switch.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: These might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571546/clr-cli-linker-fails-with-error-lnk2022-custom-attributes-are-not-consistent and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201904/how-to-use-stdafx-h-properly.

Comment: The question is moot, you cannot target 2.0 with VS2015.  The resulting assembly will always have a reference to the .NET 4.0 version of mscorlib.dll.  You must have VS2008 installed, then you can use the v9.0 toolset to build the program.